# Children in Hair Particle System got scattered

Tags: hair, particle-edit-mode

Whenever I add hair a single hair strand in particle edit, children of that hair strand are got scattered in the space. A screenshot is attached. Please Help.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Children as I understand it are basically copies of the parent particle. Yeah, they are spreading out too far. I believe there is a setting that makes them closer to the parent, but first, try just adding more particles: blender may be trying to spread the children over the entire area of the scalp.

Comment: please provide blend file because you didn't give us any useful information/settings or steps of reproduction of your problem. So i think this question will soon be close because of lack of information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Children are Hair or Emitter particles originating from individual particles. They make it possible to work primarily with a relatively low amount of Parent particles, for whom the physics are calculated. The children are then aligned to their parents. The number and visualization of the children can be changed without a recalculation of the physics."*

---

In **Simple** mode (seems to be your case) they just spread around hair particle in the same direction ...

[image]
**Radius** value make it more distance from each other.

To let children start from surface the **Interpolated** mode can handle probably what you are asking for ...

[image]

For more details see [Blender Manuall](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/children.html)